# Responsive Material Design

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I am using `Material` with `Angular 6`. I want to make my website responsive. 
What is the best option for this? I don't want to use `Bootstrap`, if I find anything better from `Material`.

Comment: well you could try using **angular material**, http://material.angular.io

Comment: Use `@angular/flex-layout` with Material

Comment: @JohnVelasquez I can't see any information regarding responsive custom design.

Comment: @Faisal, Yeah, I am looking into that only from last 15 minutes. Is there anything similar to bootstrap class? (i.e. col-lg-1 etc.)

Comment: well there is, you can use the `mat-grid-list` https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview

Comment: @JohnVelasquez If we define `col` as 2 then it is showing 2 only in small screen also.

Comment: you could try using `HostListener` to listen screen changes so that you could change your `col` in your **typescript class**

Comment: @JohnVelasquez this does not look like an ideal solution. So, many controls can be there and I can't use `HostListener` to set all control width and that is on all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular Flex-Layout is the most common choice for responsive design. You can find their responsive API docs [here](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Responsive-API).

In flex-layout, you would use `fxLayout` and `fxFlex` according to your preferences to lay out a grid for each screen size. For example `fxLayout="column"` on the parent and `fxFlex.lg="25%"` on each of 4 children to lay out a 4 equal column grid for an 'lg' screen size.